# Custom look for Google save to drive button

Tags: google-drive-api

I was wondering if there is a way to create a "Save to Drive Button" (from the [drive API here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive)) but have it use a custom look. I'd like to use that functionality, but have the button appear like the other icons that I use for social and downloads on my site, rather than the generic save button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overlay a div with the color/style you prefer and with this css property to allow click thru the div:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

and in background put the "Save to Drive Button".

Regards!